# Proving that a graph is concave given $f''<0$

Tags: real-analysis

let $f''$ exist and be negative on the interval $[0,1]$ If P and Q are points on the graph of $f$ prove that the line segment joining $P,Q$ is below the line.

Definitely need to use the mean value theorem here, but I couldn't figure out how. Any suggestions/hints?

Comment: Try contradiction.

Comment: You must mean concave. Use the fact that $f'' \lt 0$ implies that $f'$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of concave function $f : X → R$:-
$$\forall x_1, x_2 \in X, \forall t \in [0, 1]: f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\geq t f(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)$$

Let $g:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R},g(t)=f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)- (t f(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2))$. Therfore, $g(0)=g(1)=0$.

Given:$f''(x)<0$

To prove:$\forall x_1, x_2 \in X, \forall t \in [0, 1]: g(t)\ge 0$

Assume contradiction: $\exists x_1, x_2 \in X, \exists t_0 \in [0, 1]: g(t_0)< 0\space and \space \forall x\in X,f''(x)<0$

By [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) on $g$,
$$\exists c_1\in[0,t_0] : g'(c_1)=\frac{g(t_0)-g(0)}{t_0-0}=\frac{g(t_0)}{t_0}<0$$
$$\exists c_2\in[t_0,1] : g'(c_1)=\frac{g(1)-g(t_0)}{1-t_0}=\frac{-g(t_0)}{1-t_0}>0$$

By [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) on $g'$,
$$\exists c\in[c_1,c_2] : g''(c)=\frac{g'(c_2)-g'(c_1)}{c_2-c_1}=\frac{g(t_0)}{t_0}>0$$

But $g''(c)=(x_1-x_2)^2f(cx_1+(1-c)x_2)>0 \implies \exists x\in X : f''(x)>0$ which is a contradicion to our assumption.